# printf alignment with tabs in C

Tags: c, printf

I have the following print in my code

```
printf("%-*s %s", 20, "string1", "string2");
printf("%-*s %s", 20, "\tstring3", "string4");
```

I expects it to print the following:

```
string1              string2
    string3          string4
```

but on some OSs (e.g Ubuntu 16) I get the following

```
string1              string2
    string3              string4
```

I search everywhere and couldn't find a way around this, I thought `%-*s` should have solved my alignment issue but it didn't

Comment: Please provide complete code as a [mre].

Comment: This code prints four strings on a single line. It is unclear why you expect two lines of output.

Comment: I would recommend not using tabs for formatting output.

Comment: Tab characters usually require more work than handling output with spaces and the tab-width isn't a guaranteed thing. One output that exceeds a tab-width compared tothe other items in the column will cause your columns to be unaligned on each line where that occurs. Spaces on the other hand just prevent an accounting task but will be the consistent on each terminal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TAB is still 1 character. It is printed as 1 character. Then it's up to the terminal to do whatever it wants with it.

This means, `printf("%-20s", "\tstring3");` is going to print 1 TAB character, 7 normal characters, and then 12 spaces to arrive at 20.

You need to re-think what you want to do. One way would be to create a function which takes in the string with TABs in it, and returns a string where those have been expanded to spaces. If TAB is always at the start of the string, then you could just replace TABs with 8 (or however many you need) spaces. If you need actual TAB stops, you need a bit more logic to expand them to right amount of spaces.